# Number of pairs that share at least one digit

Tags: algorithm

You are given `n` numbers and you have to find the **number of pairs** such that at least one digit is common in between them.

Eg. For **5** numbers :

```
2837 2818 654 35 931
```

Answer : **6**

The pairs here are `(2837,2818), (2837,35), (2837,931), (2818,931), (654,35), (35,931)`

**My Attempt** : I took a structure which stores **the number in decimal, the number in form of its digits in array and number of digits in that number**.

Now for each number I **hashed** that number in array conatining index **0-9** and the checked with all following numbers wether any of their digit is already present.

My attempt is `O(n^2)`, which is slow.  Is there another algorithm that will work faster?

Comment: You hashed a value, but failed to use a hashtable lookup?

Comment: My solution was working correctly but taking quite a lot time when n was large

Comment: This cannot be done faster than O(n^2) because you need that O(n^2) at least to generate the answer in the worst case.

Comment: @GrigorGevorgyan - I assume that the answer for the example in the question is intended to be simply `6`.  You don't have to list all the pairs.

Comment: @JirkaHanika Yes you are correct pairs were shown for more and clear explaintion, only count is requred as answer and even in question its boldly written as "number of pairs".

Answer (score 13):

It is crucial to realize what are the variables and what are the constants here.

Number of digits is a constant (10).  So is the number of all sets of digits (1024).  So is the number of all pairs of such sets (2<sup>20</sup>, or approximately one million).  Let's take advantage of that.

Let's try and preprocess the input into an "equivalent" representation in a data structure whose size is constant (independent of input size).  Whatever we then do with that constant size structure is by definition a constant time operation, so the total running time is asymptotically determined by the preprocessing phase only.

**Data structure**

Create an array of 1024 integers, each bucket (index) corresponding to a set of digits; we want to store the number of input numbers that have exactly that set of digits in each bucket.

For example, 3606 has digits 0, 3, and 6, and so it would be counted in bucket 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>6</sup> = 73.

**Algorithm**

Preprocessing is obvious.  Take the next digit (such as `'3'`), convert it to its value (such as `3`), now compute the corresponding bit (such as `1 << 3`) and OR it into a (tentative) bucket index variable; different digits inhabit different bits so every digit combination gets a unique bucket, but we got rid of any repeating digits.  Loop like this until encountering the number separator; at that point, the bucket index is final and we can just increment the bucket, reset the bucket index and skip till the next digit.

That's it.  All that remains is to count our sheep.  Oops.  Pairs of sheep.

Compare each buckets with each other bucket (but not itself).  Whenever the two *indexes* share a digit (this can be determined using the `&` operator), multiply the content of those two buckets together, and add the product to a globally maintained sum.

Compare each bucket also to itself, and add only `x * (x - 1) / 2` to the globally maintained sum, where `x` is the content of the bucket.

That sum is your result.

**Performance**

Worst case: `O(n)` where `n` is input size.

The constant factors are favourable as well.  We needed a handful instructions (and a RAM access) per digit or separator; and the constant phase examines one million bucket pairs, spending something like another handful instructions on each pair (no RAM access needed, the data structure is very compact).  This is lightning fast.

A theorist will say that this is cheating.  We are assuming that there is no upper bound on input length (or we couldn't talk asymptotic complexity at all), and yet we also assume that we can put up to the total input length into an integer variable.  Oh, well.

A more practical programmer will note that the algorithm is exponential in alphabet size.  We've been lucky; if our words weren't composed of digits but of arbitrary characters except the separator, ours would still be asymptotically a linear time algorithm, but it would be unusably slow for any input whatsoever, compared to a naive algorithm which could easily crunch up to megabytes of input at a time.

Comment: I think in this form it has the same problem as my proposed solution, but this one might be fixable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong. I thought you double count pairs that have more than one digit in common, but you don't.

Comment: could you please explain why did you use this method of 2^0 + 2^3 + 2^6 for mapping.I am more interested in knowing how did you came up with it.

Comment: Any fixed mapping would do, as long as it never maps two different sets of digits to the same code.  I chose this one for space efficiency, cache-friendliness, and for ease of the nested iteration at the end: with this particular mapping, there are no "holes" in the array (no non-codes between valid codes).  Last but not least, this coding requires only a handful of machine instructions per character of input on any normal architecture.  No exponentiation operation is needed, because for any x, 2^x = 1 shift-to-left x.

Comment: @JirkaHanika , can u pls explain elaborately , i didnt understood above solution clearly , can u pls .. pls

Comment: Can you add some code as a working example?

Comment: @bittahProfessional - I'm unlikely to pick a language and code any part of this.  It might result in a clearer answer or in a less clear answer if I chose to do that, instead of describing and analyzing the algorithm in plain English as I did.  Feel free to submit a separate answer in your favorite programming language if you are sufficiently motivated to code this.

Answer (score 0):

create a an array of sets, one for each digit.

iterate your numbers and put each number in each set for the digits it contains.

iterate of all 10 sets and combine every element of a set with all other elements in the same set. (or all other elements larger than itself, if you don't want (a,b) and (b,a) in your result.

I think this is still O(n^2) but it could be paralized nicely using a fork join approach.

**update**

Just realized you only want the number of results. So that would be the sum of size * size-1 for all sets. Since inserting into a set and getting its size should be linear (I think) this might actually be O(n)

**anotherupdate**

If your numbers a distinct and you are only interested in the number of pairs, you don't even need sets, you just need a counter instead.

**doesn't work**
From the comments:

```
Consider 1st pair in above questions test case (2837,2818), this will put first number in set containing digit 2 and 8 and same for 2818 now they are to be counted as one but counting in 2 and 8 will count it twice. I hope you understand what I am trying to say...
```

So this approach doesn't work ... I guess it might be of value as a warning for others.

Comment: Enumerating the pairs, rather than just computing the number of them, necessarily takes Ω(n²) time in the worst case, since there are O(n²) of them.

Comment: @larsmans you are right, I just realized only the number of pairs is needed. Edited the answer.

Comment: @L.ppt what do you mean by digit can be very big? Do you mean n can be very big? Or do you mean each number can be very big? If n can be up to 10^18 you have a problem I think.

Comment: @L.ppt: What decimal digit (not a number!) is bigger than 9?

Comment: so the numbers have up to 18 digits ... since this is just a constant in the O() estimate and not a huge one, it is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: @JensSchauder Consider 1st pair in above questions test case (2837,2818), this will put first number in set containing digit 2 and 8 and same for 2818 now they are to be counted as one but counting in 2 and 8 will count it twice. I hope you understand what I am trying to say...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I notice that the position of common digits does not matter.

In that case, I sketch a little algorithm with hash table: form 10 bins, one for each digit. Then, for each number, put (uniquely) the ID of the number in each bin corresponding to each digit it has. This operation is O(n*k), k is the number of digits of numbers. Finally, to form all pairs, take pairs of numbers inside each bin. To remove possibly doublons, arrange each pairs (a,b) with a

I think the worst case is in fact O(n^2); in fact, I do think that this step must have a complexity of O(n^2) as you want to take all pairs (at max n*(n+1)/2). So the final complexity is really quadratic.